# ActionScript #include "Demo.as" Syntax Error

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am working on a few demos getting Flash applications running Android. I was able to download the AIR SDK and can run a simple Flash application that displayed "Hello, world!" on my Android device.

Then, to complicate the application, I created an empty text field and converted it to a movie clip and named it "text_mc". Then in the frame I set the AS to

```
_root.displayText();
stop();
```

Then I went to the Scene where execution begins and did:

```
#include "Demo.as"
```

Then I created Demo.as in the same folder as demo.fla.

```
var title = "Hello, world!";

function displayTitle()
{
    text_mc.header_txt.text = title;
}
```

I try and build and receive the following error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1093: Syntax error.
```

That line is `#include "Demo.as"`. I pulled up some old flash applications I had worked on a while back and that's exactly how it was imported before. I tried adding a semicolon to the end, but it didn't change anything. What am I missing? How do I include an ActionScript file to execute it's functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm behind on the times... to include external ActionScript now it appears you need to use import rather than include.

Changing the line to `import Demo` resolved the error.

Comment: You should accept your own answer and close the question, then.

Comment: I can't for two days. When I can, I will.

Answer (score 2):

AS2: #include "Demo.as"

AS3: include "Demo.as"

***include*** behaves the same as if you copy and paste the file contents into your code.
***import*** makes a class available for use within your code.